# Want "slow effect" when toggle between two functions?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want slow animation when toggle between two functions..to understand consider following toggle function.

```
$("p").toggle(function(){$("p").css({"color": "red"});},
function(){$("p").css({"color": "blue"});
});
```

how can i give "slow" as parameter in this scenario???

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 2):

**You can use css transition:**

**An example:**

Imagine you have a button, and when you press it yo want to change the background color of a DIV with a nice transition.  So, we have a Button and a DIV, lest do it:

**jsfiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/obpxsyq3/

**HTML:**

```
<button id='mybutton'>
   Try me!
</button>
<br>
    <br>
<div id='target_div'>

</div
```

**css:**

```
#target_div {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;   
  border: 1px solid #000;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 2s; /* Safari */
  transition: background-color 2s;
}

.transition_class {
  background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

**Javascript/Jquery:**

```
$('#mybutton').click(function() {
  $('#target_div').addClass('transition_class');
});
```

I suggest you to read a little about css transitions, you're going to love!

**Hope this helps!**

Comment: You should improve your answer by including some example code. Link only answers are generally frowned upon as the link could break at any time making your answer useless for future visitors.

Comment: Hope this helps you guys!

Comment: maybe take a look at http://api.jquery.com/animate/ for browser that don't support CSS transition

Comment: JQuery does its magic using direct javascript and css.  JQuery is an abstraction or a service that provides tools to execute in an easy way what you can do using direct javascript and css.  My point is, for situations like above I think it's better use direct css.